# Error while sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade command in cmd

Tags: magento2.3

```
  Replace App And Pub Folder of Theme In Magento2.        
  After that Run Following Command : **sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
```

> PHP Warning:
>   require(/var/www/html/magento2/bin/../app/bootstrap.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento on line 14
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www                                             /html/magento2/bin/../app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento on line 14

Comment: what you have do? Does this before working fine?

Comment: yes before its Working fine